# ExtJs 4, How to prevent xtype: 'combo' from collapsing when already selected item clicked?

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox, extjs4

I have `ComboBox`. When I click on item from expanded list, `ComboBox` select this item and collapse. If I click on already selected item it also collapsing.

**Is there a way to "stop"** `ComboBox` **collapsing when user select already selected item?**

PS: to be short i want `ComboBox` to behave like `TimeField` from http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/themes/index.html

**UPDATE**

I don't need solutions that dosen't work at least at IE7 and IE8..

Comment: if you won't know the answer then at least vote for it, so other could find this question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want that behaviour:

```
Ext.form.field.ComboBox.override({
    onItemClick: Ext.emptyFn
});
```

Comment: You got a tip from one of the developer team and tell him it don't work!? Maybe you should take a closer look at your code. You can just extend or override. To fix it you should post the code that you used instead of the the Ext.emptyFn

Comment: Wow.. Sorry it works.. the problem was that after i select same content i changed displayValue, so ComboBox was collapsing becose of it, you soulution is actually works... tnx again

Answer (score 4):

```
var cb = new Ext.form.ComboBox({    
    // here is your local store
    mode: 'local',
    store: new Ext.data.SimpleStore({
        fields: ['id', 'label'],
        data: [
            ['1', 'One'],
            ['2', 'Two']
        ]
    }),    
    listeners: {
        'beforeselect': function (combo, record, index) {
            // prevent collapsing if the same value is selected
            if (record.data.label == combo.getRawValue()) return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

If it's 3.3 you're dealing with, this seems to work:

```
Ext.form.ComboBox.override({
  onSelect : Ext.form.ComboBox.prototype.onSelect.createInterceptor(function(record) {
    return this.getValue() !== record.data[this.valueField || this.displayField];
  })
});
```

Tested on Chrome and IE8. It prevents the `onSelect` function being called if it the current value exactly matches the value you're trying to set.

Comment: The solution described by @Evan Trimboli works fine in IE8 for ExtJS 4.